# Python multiprocessing code can only be run in terminal or debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm, multiprocessing

I can only run the following code by executing it in terminal or by runing it in the debug mode.

It seems that it is something about the portability issue (I guess), but can someone explain it?

I saw some tutorial emphasising the importance of `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but I, as a python rookie, can hardly understand.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def add_abc(a, b, c):
    print(a + b + c)


def main():

    # Create a list of information
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    c = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

    processes = []

    # Create a list of processes
    for i in range(5):
        p = mp.Process(target=add_abc, args=(a[i], b[i], c[i]))
        processes.append(p)

    # Start the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Join the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

If I run it in the pycharm's normal Run mode (Shift + F10), I get `EOFError` and `_pickle.PicklingError`:
(Just part of Error message)

```
  File "D:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function add_abc at 0x0000023408E3C540>: attribute lookup add_abc on __main__ failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 120, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 130, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Normal Output should be:

```
18
21
24
27
30
```

Comment: It seems to work fine within VSCode on windows and wsl-ubuntu (Python 3.10.8)

Comment: That's weird. I use Pycharm on Windows and Python 3.11. And I have already reinstalled Python and created a brand-new virtual environment.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your _exact_ run configuration? "normal" doesn't tell use much. Please also mention which version of PyCharm you're using. PyCharm's run configuration settings have changed in the last few versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an IDE problem. Python has 2 modes of operation: normal and interactive. Think of normal mode as running a ".py" file from a terminal, and interactive as typing code into a prompt one line at a time. Multiprocessing also has two different modes of operation that are impacted by this normal and interactive operation: Spawning and Forking. Forking is not available on Windows, and is not the default on MacOS. This problem sounds like a bad interaction between running python in interactive mode while using multiprocessing in spawning mode.

> Why you need `if __name__ == "__main__":`

When you attempt to "spawn" a new process, it will attempt to `import` the main file from which it was created. If importing the script is just like running it, then importing the script will cause it to try and create its own child process which will import - create a new process - import... causing an infinite loop which could create infinite child processes. This is why we use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to prevent the script from creating any child processes (or doing anything really other than defining functions classes and maybe some static data). `__name__` is a special variable which will be `"__main__"` only when you run that file. If the file is imported, it will be the name of the "module" (the file name in this case: "test").

> What I think the actual error message is:

The main issue is also related to importing if you are using interactive mode. Depending on the IDE you may not even realize you're using interactive mode, but if you are then python doesn't have a "main" file to import when the child process starts up. Basically when a new process is started via "spawn" it knows nothing about its parent process. It only has a "pipe" to communicate with the parent, and it knows that it needs to follow the standard python "spawn" startup procedure (from: python\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py). The parent process will attempt to send the info needed over that pipe for the child to execute what you want, but there's one more small detail. The communication protocol used ("Pickle") cannot send functions or class definitions directly. Instead it sends instructions on how to import the correct definitions. Finally we arrive at the issue: there is no ".py" file to import if you defined the function in interactive mode. Sometimes you can get around this by putting the target function in a separate file which can be imported, and sometimes IDE's do some dark magic to get it to work in a non-standard way. Typically I simply prefer to use an IDE that only executes code from a file, and I only use the interactive mode for small experiments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer addresses some of my concerns. May I ask how can I determine whether the Pycharm is running in interactive mode? Because I have used it to run other codes with a bunch of imports before, but nothing strange came up.

Comment: @JiangpengLi Do you have "Run with Python console" enabled in your run configuration settings?

Comment: I don't use pycharm, so I can't really tell you. Generally it would be something along the lines of "run configuration". I use Spyder, (which uses IPython shell for interactive mode), and in the past using the "run in existing terminal" would cause this error, and I had to set the run configuration to "run in external terminal". Spyder has since implemented some of that "dark magic" to get it working.

Comment: @Brian61354270 That's right. Finally solve it. I will edit Aaron's answer with screenshots.

Comment: @JiangpengLi looks like others have had this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50116) and come to the same conclusion that they must un-check "run with python console". Unfortunately Pycharm doesn't have any "dark magic" of its own yet, but without that, this is the expected result of pure vanilla python.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running your script from the package special `__main__.py` file,
and it looks like pickle can't manage that.

try to rename you file to something else like mymod.py and then run `python -m mypkg/mymod`

Comment: This script's name is `test.py`. And I have renamed it to something like `my_script.py` before.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with your run configurations in PyCharm. When I copy paste your code it executes normally on my machine (PyCharm 2023.2, Windows 11).

Do you have something special in your run configurations?

PS: Sorry, that I'm posting this as an answer - have no permissions to comment yet.

Comment: Nope. The Pycharm is also basically brand-new. I just added several TODO patterns inside.

Things are getting weird right now.